Mac Mini M2 Pro USB devices not recognized via monitor usb hub
I'm struggling with a strange problem, with a oled Philips Evnia 49M2C8900 connected to my Mac Mini M2 Pro. The monitor has a KVM functionality, so you can use 2 machine connected, one with video and data on 1 usbc cable, the other on HDMI or DP + a usb upstream cable usb3: the monitor also has 4 usb ports where I connected all my pheripherals, including mouse and keyboard. Let's focus on the usbc cable: when it's connected to my Dell working laptop all works as expected, full resolution, full refresh rate, all usb devices recognized. The same cable connected on a usb c port on my Mac Mini M2 Pro raises the problem: the video works well, but the usb devices don't. Not the keyboard or mouse or any other devices connected to the monitor. The cable is a Cable Matters high quality usb4 cable, but I tried other cables, even a TB3 cable. The same behavior happens on a Macbook Air M2. On the monitor you can change the functionality of the Usbc subsystem from 3.2 to 2.0, but I tried in both ways, no luck. Any clues?
Thanks

Welcome to Superuser. Please consider editing your post to break it up into paragraphs, clarifying the issue, using more common formatting, etc. This will help make your post more comprehensible.

Check USB-C Compatibility: Ensure that your Mac Mini M2 Pro supports USB-C DP Alt Mode and USB-C Power Delivery, as these are necessary for video and USB data transmission.
Update macOS: Make sure your Mac Mini M2 Pro.
Reset SMC and NVRAM.
Ensure the USB-C port is configured correctly.
Sometimes, toggling the USB-C functionality between 3.2 and 2.0 and restarting both devices.
Try connecting different USB devices to the monitor to see if any of them are recognized by the Mac Mini to determine if the issue is with specific peripherals...
If you have, connect a powered USB hub to the monitor and then connect your peripherals to the hub.
You can contact Philips support for assistance.

Hi, already tried all of your suggestions, the Mac is updated and is compatible with the functionality, I used many times with an older Dell monitor. I already contacted Philips but no feedback at this time. Thanks
